# python urllib, urllib2 how to get SHARP links

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize, urllib, cookielib

okey my dear helpers, here is the question, I can not get the 
' http://example.com/#sharplink ', by the way in the site making infinite loop so I used redirect handler and it need to enable the cookielibrary,

here is the my codes

```
import urllib2, urllib, cookielib


urllib.FancyURLopener.version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092814 (Debian-3.0.1-1)'

class MyHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def redirect_request(self, req, fb, code, msg, headers, newurl):
        m = req.get_method()
        if (code in (301, 302, 303, 307) and m in ('GET', 'HEAD') or code in (301, 302, 303) and m == 'POST'):
            newurl = newurl.replace(' ', '%20')
            newheaders = dict((k,v) for k,v in req.headers.items()
                    if k.lower() not in ("content-length", "content-type")
                    )
            return urllib2.Request(newurl,
                headers=newheaders,
                origin_req_host=req.get_origin_req_host(),
                unverifiable=True)
        else:
            raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, headers, fp)


cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(MyHTTPRedirectHandler, urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/goto/#sharplink')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

f=open('bet','w')
f.write(response.read())
f.close()
```

but every time I just can get ' http://example.com/goto ' page not the sharp page, please help me !!!

Answer (score 1):

The fragment part of an URL ("sharplink") is not sent to the webserver (it's commonly used to define a specific section on the given webpage that a link refers to), so it doesn't matter whether you request `http://example.com/goto/` or `http://example.com/goto/#sharplink`.

If you expect the pages to be different, then most likely the site uses an AJAX framework which encodes state in the fragment part of the URL. As `urllib` and friends do not execute JS, you'd need to use something like `phantomjs` to get the content of the page.

Comment: dude thanks, I solved the issue with phantomjs, it is usefull, good luck :)

Comment: Glad to hear you could solve your problem. Mind accepting this answer? ;)

Comment: but I have to say it was not the what I want exactly, because I was trying to make a hard coded bot in order to get some important data from server, but those datas are stored very safely, so couple research actually there is no way to get # sharp link, but if the problem needed to be solved and if it is serious thing, so find an another way to solve it, for me I made the whole computer a bot, like humanless computer 7/24 working for me, but thanks anyway I just learned how to use phantomjs